# Plot multiple images on the same graph in python using FigureCanvasTkAgg

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I want to plot multiple images on the same graph in python using FigureCanvasTkAgg.When using matplotlib I could use {import matplotlib.pyplot as plt} `plt.imshow(image1) ; plt.pause(0.6) ; plt.imshow(image2)`
Since I use Tkinter,I make use of FigureCanvasTkAgg to do the same

```
   `f = Figure(figsize=(6,6))

    a = f.add_subplot(111)
    image = np.array(np.random.random((1024,1024))*100,dtype=int)
    a.imshow(image)

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)`
```

Could anyone please help me in how to achieve pause effect of matplotlib in FigureCanvasTkAgg.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `threading` module to schedule the execution of a function:

```py
from threading import Thread

def wrapper():
    time.sleep(5)
    image = np.array(np.random.random((1024,1024))*100,dtype=int)
    ax.imshow(image)
    canvas.draw()

_t = Thread(target=wrapper)
_t.start()
```

This will execute the function `wrapper` in a new thread, so the original program can go on meanwhile.

Here the full example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

root = tk.Tk()
f = Figure(figsize=(6,6))

ax = f.add_subplot(111)
# First image    
image = np.array(np.random.random((1024,1024))*100, dtype=int)
ax.imshow(image)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

def wrapper():
    time.sleep(5)
    # Second image appears after 5 seconds
    image = np.array(np.random.random((1024,1024))*100,dtype=int)
    ax.imshow(image)
    canvas.draw()

_t = Thread(target=wrapper)
_t.start()

root.mainloop()
```